# Proving $f(n) = O(g(n)) \Rightarrow lg(f(n)) = O(lg(g(n)))$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Say you have to prove that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ implies $lg(f(n)) = O(lg(g(n)))$, where $lg(g(n)) \geq 1$ and $f(n) \geq 1$ for all sufficiently large n.

The solution is given as
[image]

So I do understand the individual parts of the proof. However, I do *not* understand why we are not done after the $\Rightarrow lg f(n) \leq lg(c g(n)) = lg c + lg (g(n))$?

I mean since we already know that $0 \leq f(n) \leq c g (n)$ is true, doesn't it suffice simply to take the logarithm of the inequality? Why, why not? Why does the solution proceed to additional steps after this?

Comment: The definition of "$\lg f(n) = O(\lg g(n))$" is "there exists a constant $d$ for which $\lg f(n) \le d \lg g(n)$ for all large $n$." The first conclusion $\lg f(n) \le \lg c + \lg g(n)$ is not quite the same as this, so you need to do a little more work to get to the actual definition.

Comment: But since log is a monotonically increasing function why does it not suffice to take the log of the inequality that we already know is true? It should still preserve the truth of the inequality, right?

Comment: Monotonicity of the logarithm allows you to go from $f(n) \le c g(n)$ to $\lg f(n) \le \log c + \lg g(n)$. How do you conclude "\lg f(n) \le d \lg g(n)$" from this?

Comment: Well, you also need to find a multiplicative constant which makes the inequality true. Right now, by just taking the log of the definition, you will only have an additive constant.